# find out what query is a process making knowing the PID of it

Tags: mysql, debugging, cpu-usage

By using htop command, I can see one mysqld process is taking more than 500% CPU usage and the PID of it is for example 20456
htop only show command /usr/bin/mysqld next to it

Now, what I would like to do is to examine what query is that PID making? My website does a lot of things related to database and I want to know what job cause this high CPU usage. Can someone show me the way please?

I tried show full processlist in mysql but it doesn't show me the PID in that list so I don't know what to focus on.

Comment: Please post text results of SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; so we can see what you are looking at. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 5.7 / 8.0 seams to have native support for that, when i look into the [threads view manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/threads-table.html)

> THREAD_OS_ID
>
> The thread or task identifier as defined by the underlying operating
>   system, if there is one:
>
> THREAD_OS_ID contains the operating system
>   thread ID.
>
> For Windows, THREAD_OS_ID corresponds to the thread ID visible in
>   Process Explorer
>   (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).
>
> For Linux, THREAD_OS_ID corresponds to the value of the gettid()
>   function. This value is exposed, for example, using the perf or ps -L
>   commands, or in the proc file system (/proc/[pid]/task/[tid]). For
>   more information, see the perf-stat(1), ps(1), and proc(5) man pages

Besides this view also contains a `PROCESSLIST_ID` column so you can JOIN it with the [information_schema.processlist](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/processlist-table.html) to know which query is using which OS PID's

Comment: "These are server threads, not client threads" The topicstarter needs the server threads @user207421 he is talking about `mysqld` so this method is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried from root logon when the query is running -

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.innodb_trx;

?
```

to see the content of the query(s) running?

Comment: @nagedev207  Have you tried this technique to see the query(s) running?